# I have a column of dates in varchar and i need to convert to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, converters

The dates are currently displayed as: `ddmmmyyyy` (12DEC2013)

I've been playing around with this formula:

```
DECLARE @Date char(8)
set @Date='12312009'
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(@Date,4)+LEFT(@Date,2)+SUBSTRING(@Date,3,2))
```

but I didn't have any success, can someone help me out with this. Additionally all my dates are in a column called `TERMDT` and I'd like to put all the new date values in a new column formatted as such.

Comment: Is this mysql or sql-server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: And why of why are you storing dates as varchar? You really need to use the proper datatypes.

Comment: sql server, sorry about that.

Comment: I received this huge terribly formatted table and I need to run all these queries on it which are virtually impossible to do as is. I would've never created the table this way.

Comment: My concern is you are talking about changing the format. You need to change the datatype. A datetime is not stored with a format. Hopefully your new column is a date or datetime column. Will eliminate all this kind of pain.

Comment: definitely is, i plan on getting rid of the current "date" column.. let me run your answer right now

Comment: @midiman Specify the version of the SQL server: SELECT @@VERSION

Comment: msft sql server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3153.0 (X64)

Answer (score 1):

Just give `convert()` an appropriate 3rd argument (the format):

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,
               RIGHT(d, 4) + LEFT(d,2) + SUBSTRING(d, 3, 2),
               112)
from (select '12312009' as d) t
```