# Conversion failing (converting date and/or time from character string)

Tags: sql, sql-server, converters

I'm trying to run a query where I convert a varchar column (TERM) that stores dates in ddmmmyyyy format in to a proper date column (DATE) but i keep encountering an error. This is the code i'm running:

```
Update TABLE
set DATE = CAST(  CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, TERM) AS VARCHAR(4))  + '-'
    + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, TERM)  AS VARCHAR(2))+ '-'
    + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, TERM)  AS VARCHAR(2)) AS DATE)
```

I keep getting the Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string not sure why. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you show some sample rows of the data on the Term Field?

Comment: What data type is the target column DATE ?

Comment: Didn't you ask pretty much the same question twice already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729645/how-can-i-parse-a-varchar-string-into-three-columns-year-month-and-day http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727125/i-have-a-column-of-dates-in-varchar-and-i-need-to-convert-to-date

Comment: @ericpap I should've clarified, sample data from the term field are:
12DEC2012
20OCT2013
And yes target is a date

Comment: @jpw not to my understanding, but I am willing to admit that it's limited so who knows. apologies if i have been redundant

Comment: Probably you have invalid data. Your original code works under both `SET LANGUAGE English;` and `SET LANGUAGE British;` (but of course it relies on implicitly converting to date when you pass it to the datetime functions and if it implicitly converts OK you don't need to do this in the first place)

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you Martin, was really hoping that wasn't the answer but I suspected it might be. Is there anyway I can negate all values in the source field that aren't in the recognized DDMMMYYYY format?

Comment: `SELECT TERM FROM T WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, TERM) IS NULL` or `SELECT TERM FROM T WHERE ISDATE(TERM) = 0` depending on what version you are on.

Comment: @MartinSmith i'll try them both now, thank you!!

Comment: Also a good choise will be use TRY_PARSE if you store data as string value: SELECT TRY_PARSE(TERM AS date) FROM T depend on version you're using

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko thanks! that'll definitely be helpful for my next fields!

Comment: @MartinSmith you can submit your suggestion as an answer because it worked :D thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

If the source data is a string don't use `DATEPART` - use `SUBSTRING`:

```
Update TABLE
set DATE = CAST(
      SUBSTRING(TERM,1,2) + '-'
    + SUBSTRING(TERM,3,3) + '-'
    + SUBSTRING(TERM,6,4)
           AS DATE)
```

Comment: Still getting the conversion failed error, I'm pretty sure it's bad data at this point. Thank you for your suggestion though, i'll keep substring in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run `datepart` on a string.  It is a *date* function.  You want something like this:

```
Update TABLE
    set DATE = CONVERT(date,
                       (LEFT(TERM, 4) + ' ' +
                        SUBSTRING(TERM, 3, 3) + ' ' +
                        RIGHT(TERM, 4)
                       ), 106
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to couple the conversion of type with a test that the conversion will succeed, such as by using [ISDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms187347.aspx) that returns 1 if the parameter can be evaluated to a date.

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(String_Date VARCHAR(9), Real_Date DATE)

INSERT INTO @TABLE 
  (String_Date)
VALUES 
   ('31DEC2013')
  ,('26NOV2013')
  ,('22SEP2013')
  ,('31DEC2013')
  ,('31DEC2013')
  ,('rubbish')
```

### Query

```
UPDATE @TABLE
SET Real_Date =  CASE WHEN ISDATE(String_Date) = 1 THEN CAST( String_Date AS DATE) END
FROM @TABLE

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
;
```

### Result

```
| STRING_DATE |  REAL_DATE |
|-------------|------------|
|   31DEC2013 | 2013-12-31 |
|   26NOV2013 | 2013-11-26 |
|   22SEP2013 | 2013-09-22 |
|   31DEC2013 | 2013-12-31 |
|   31DEC2013 | 2013-12-31 |
|     rubbish |     (null) |
```

---

[DATEPART( datepart, date)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms174420.aspx)  can be used on a string:

> date Is an expression that can be resolved to a time, date,
>   smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2, or datetimeoffset value. date can
>   be an expression, column expression, user-defined variable, or **string
>   literal**.

The same result could be achieved using `DATEPART`

### Query b

```
UPDATE @TABLE
SET Real_Date =  CASE WHEN ISDATE(String_Date) = 1 THEN
                       CAST(  CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, String_Date) AS VARCHAR(4))  
                            + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, String_Date)  AS VARCHAR(2)) ,2)
                            + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, String_Date)  AS VARCHAR(2)) ,2) AS DATE) 
                 END
FROM @TABLE

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```